# PHP/MySQL Activerecord, get relationship row count

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, relational-database

I have two tables:

```
media_folders
id, title

media
id, folder_id, title
```

They each have their own model

`Media, MediaFolder`. Nothing special about them except they have the `static $table_name` property set. Now I can assign a `$has_many` to the `MediaFolder` class which will find all associated `Media`. However, All i need is to get the number of media within a mediafolder and not the actual objects themselves. I want to end up with an attribute in a `MediaFolder` object called `files` which has a count of how many media rows has a `folder_id` of the current folder.

How would i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Understand your case, but not your exact problem so can you provide some more details like:
1. does your problem is with building SQL query?
2. does your problem with building query using active records.. (if yes which framework you are using)
Need some more description.

Comment: Basically, I just want to have a property in MediaFolder called files which has a count of all associated Media rows without generating a Media object for every row. My work around is a custom query and a method called get_files_count but I was wondering if there was a built in way to do this with PHP ActiveRecord.

Comment: Yes its there in PHP Active record, as I am using codeigniter framework which provide this support. Here is an link of one of its example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599488/codeigniter-active-record-select-left-join-count

Answer (score 0):

If it's just some SQL :

```
$sql = "SELECT mf.folder_id, count(m.id) as files
          FROM media_folders mf, media m
         WHERE mf.id = m.folder_id
         GROUP BY mf.folder_id"
```